# (Un)Serialize JSON (to)in QObject using nlohmann/json

Tags: qt, nlohmann-json

I want to use the [nlohmann/json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) library to serialize some json to a QObject and vice versa.

The problem I run into is that the parser is trying to use the copy constructor of the QObject, wish is not allowed.

There is something in the documentation regarding this https://github.com/nlohmann/json#how-can-i-use-get-for-non-default-constructiblenon-copyable-types but I can't manage to make it work.

```
template <>
struct adl_serializer<MyQObject>
{
    static MyQObject from_json(const json& j)
    {
        return {j.get<MyQObject>()}; // call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'MyQObject'
    }

    static void to_json(json& j, MyQObject t)
    {
        j = t; // no viable overload '='
    }
};

inline void from_json(const json& j, MyQObject& x)
{
    x.setXxx(j.at("xxx").get<typeOfXxx>()):
    // ...
}

inline void to_json(json& j, const MyQObject& x)
{
    j = json::object();
    j["xxx"] = x.xxx();
    // ...
}
```

What should I write in the adl_serializer to make it work ?

Comment: What kind of data and how are you going to store in your `QObject`?

Comment: @vahancho mainly basic types and other QObject-derived classes. The function "from_json(const json& j, MyQObject& x)" is used to fill the QObject (as shown in the documentation https://github.com/nlohmann/json#basic-usage).

Comment: Can you bring an example of storing JSON like data in a `QObject`?

Comment: I don't want to store it as JSON data but unserialize it in the object. Something like `MyQObject myObject = nlohmann::json::parse(jsonStr);`